Pyspark error An error occurred while calling o35.load
This is my spark session
SparkSession.builder
    .appName('SparkDataStreaming')
    .config('spark.jars.packages', "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.13:3.4.1", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.4.1")
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost')
    .getOrCreate()

when I try to use
spark_conn.readStream
    .format('kafka')
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092')
    .option('subscribe', 'user_created')
    .load()

It's return An error occurred while calling o35.load.
enter image description here
I already add dependencies jar file and kafka was running normally on localhost:9092(testing already)

pyspark 3.4.1
java 11

How can I fix it?

I may assume that problem is in wrong kafka connector version. You can try 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.4.1', but it is hard to say.
